# How do I choose the next item after using Autocomplete in the Python Console?

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

The list that populates below `bpy.` after using *Autocomplete* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) in the *Python Console* is: `app`, `context`, `data`, `ops`, `path`, `props`, `types` and `utils`.

I'm trying to select `ops`. The video just shows click and move on any suggestions?

Comment: Can you link to the video? I always add the next letter so bpy.o then CTRL+SPACE to get the autocomplete. If necessary add additional characters to ensure the uniqueness. You could also double click on item in the result and the CTRL+c CTRL+v to copy and paste it in the correct place.

Comment: @rob i think the second sentence should be an answer. So this question can get closed.

Comment: the repeating of cntrl + spacebar and finishing of word than . followed with word than . and cntrl + spacebar allows me to navigate.  thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete functionality relies on uniqueness.

So **bpy.**<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>
lists all the objects in the **bpy** name space.

And **bpy.o**<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>
results in the single value **ops** as nothing else starts with **o**

When the match is ambiguous e.g. **bpy.p**<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>
you get two results

```
ath
rops
```

(for **path** and **props**)

There is no way to use keyboard shortcuts to select the correct entry, but if you double click on the item you want the entire item will be selected and then you can copy and paste <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Remember Blender is open source, so in theory you could submit a patch that would add additional functionality to the Python console.

Comment: Script wise, could override auto complete operator_`2.80/scripts/startup/bl_operators/console.py`_Re the console history.. Looked into patching the source to make  the history work more akin to gvim, where the history (up down arrow) also takes into account whats in the buffer to match a previous command. Use autocomplete alot .. but often find myself pecking like a chicken to find a command in history.